# javascript queues in runtime and their priority level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime, v8

In the java script runtime process why microtask queue has higher priority than callback queue.?

and also how many more different queue are there and what is priority level

Answer (score 0):

> In the java script runtime process why microtask queue has higher priority than callback queue?

Because the specification says so.

> and also how many more different queue are there and what is priority level?

That depends on the embedding you are talking about. The main event queue and the microtask queue are the two important concepts. Node.js, for example, has some very fine-grained documentation about the details at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/. For a browser focus, you can read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide/In_depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this out in the [processing model section of the WHATWG specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model).
It's not very easy to read but it's the most official source.

In a web environment you will typically have different types of events for which you'd want to have different priorities, thus we have different queues.

There's also an animation queue you can enqueue on with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame).